# Relationship between the trace distance and the operator norm for some time dependent integral operator with kernel $K(x,y,t)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, asymptotics, compact-operators

Let us assume that $L_{K_{t}}$ is a positive, compact operator with time dependent kernel $K(x,y,t)$.

I know that for self adjoint operators

$$ \|A\| = max_{n} |\lambda_{n}|$$

where $\lambda_{n}$ are eigen values (point spectrum elements of $A$).

I also know that for the trace distance $\| A\|_{1} := Tr\{A^{\dagger}A\}$.

$$\| A\|_{1} = \sum_{n}|\lambda_{n}|$$

My question is the following.

Let us assume that assymptotically $L_{K_{t}}$ has zero operator norm. i.e.
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \|L_{K_{t}}\| = 0 $$

does this not imply that

$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} max_{n}|\lambda_{n}(t)| = 0 $$

and consequently that

$$ \lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n}|\lambda_{n}(t)| =0$$

Comment: Do you assume that the operators with kernel $K(x,y;t)$ are compact ?

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes I do! I'll add this in.

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is not true. Consider $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ and $t\ge 1.$
$$K(i,j,t)= \begin{cases} t^{-1/2} & i=j\le t \\
0 & {\rm otherwise}\end{cases} $$
Then
$$\|L_{K_t}\|=t^{-1/2},\qquad {\rm tr}\,L_{K_t}=t^{-1/2}[t]$$
Thus the norms tend to $0,$ while the trace norms tend to $\infty.$

Comment: Very interesting example. For a kernel such as $K(x,y,t) = \frac{1}{\pi}e^(-x^2-y^2-t(x-y)^2) $ (positve self adjoint operator) the trace $T\{rL_{K_{t}}\} = \int dx K(x,x,t) = 1\forall t$ but $\|L_{K_{t}}\| \rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ since $\|L_{K_{t}}\|\leq \in\int dxdy K^{2}(x,y,t)$ and the latter interal clearly goes to zero since the volume of the integrand goes to zero for large $t$. Would this also work as a counter example?

Comment: Sorry for the lengthy message, I am tryin to construct my own counter example as well. I was hoping to forge a counter example $K(x,y,t) \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2})$.

Comment: No problem. My counterexample is also a Hilbert-Schmidt operator, whose Hilbert-Schmidt norm is equal approximately $1$ for $t\to \infty$